# How to put a value in Scenario Outline Examples (karate framework)?

Tags: karate

In my feature I have:

```
* def loc = responseHeaders['location'][10]
* def id = loc.substring(loc.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
```

And I would like to use id in scenario outline examples:

```
Scenario Outline: fkdfslqknfd
    Given url 'foo.com'
    And path <bar>
    When method get
    ......    
        Examples:
          |bar |
          |(id)|
          |"id"|
          |'id'|
          |id  |> The last example is ok.
```

But instead of receiving `'foo.com/13'` (assuming that id is 13) I have `'foo.com/id'`. I tried with #, but it doesn't work. How I can replace this id? I need to test this id put in String format. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation of Cucumber, that the `Examples` cannot be dynamic. Refer to this last paragraph of the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#the-karate-way

If you are really trying to loop over a feature with different values, again, refer to the above doc, and there are plenty of examples if you look around. Look at all the ones that start with `call-` here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. The question is not in dynamic Examples. I didn't explained well. I know in advance how many examples I'll have. I just need to put id in String form. Instead of writing 13 like here      Examples:
          |bar |
          |(13)|
          |"13"|
          |'13' |
          |13  |     I need to put id in " " and ' ' like here     Examples:
          |bar |
          |(id)|
          |"id"|
          |'id'|
          |id  |     But instead of url/13 I have url/id

Answer (score 2):

At least within JSON parameter, it was working for me

```
 Examples:
| request_body |
| {username: '#(email)', password: '#(password)'} |
```